# Is CORs really related with problem? or Is there another problem?

Tags: docker, webpack, server, hosting

I tried to install indigo eln, open-source electronical lab notebook. But there was a problem. My server is part of computer from cafe24 in South Korea.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bomfW.jpg)

First of all, there is something going to wrong with get localhost:8080........ there is no http.
and then dev tool in Firefox said:

> Others are cached or just transferred. but account and client
> configuration were 'NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K4z7.jpg)

Finally, I saw dev tool in Firefox's debug tool with invalid host header and something about CORs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD8A3.jpg)

I tried as much as I can... but I don't know why this error happened. Cafe24 said, your OS is Centos 7 and amount of disk was distributed.
Yes, my server is not whole computer, I think it is part of computer with some OS.
Anyway, is CORs related to my error?

I tried to edit webpack.dev.config in indigo-eln's UI container.
but there were no effect.